# Determine whether the relation ⇢ is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, asymmetric or transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Determine whether the relation ⇢ is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric,
asymmetric or transitive

$(p \subset \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z) \times (\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z)$ where $(a, b)  p (c, d)$ if and only if $a \le c$.

The solutions says "The relation is reflexive and transitive." but why isn't it anti-symmetric ?

Comment: Have a look at this page for future reference: [How to Ask](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice).

Comment: Well, $(a,1)\times (a,2)$ and $(a,2)\times (a,1)$.

Comment: I assume that $(a,b)\times(c,d)$ is supposed to be $(a,b)\to(c,d)$. It’s not antisymmetric because $(0,1)\to(0,2)$ and $(0,2)\to(0,1)$, but $(0,1)\ne(0,2)$.

Comment: anti symetric means if ApB and BpA then A=B.  (a,b)p(c,d) = (c,d)p(a,b) means $a \le c; c \le a$ so $a= c$ but it doesn't say anything about b and d.  b and d can be anything you want.  (a, 1) p(a,2) and (a,2)p(a,1) but (a,1) $\ne$ (a,2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $(a,b)p(c,d)$ and $(c,d) p(a,b)$ then $a \le c$ and $c \le a$.  So $a = c$.

If p is anti-symmetric then it would also follow that $(c,d) = (a,b)$ so $d = b$.

Suppose $b \ne d$.  Then $(a,b) p(a,d)$ because $a \le a$.  And $(a,d) p(a,b)$ because $a \le a$.  But can we conclude that $b = d$?

No.  Because .... they aren't.

So p is not anti-symmetric.